# A stereographic projection for the Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials, stereographic-projections

This question may be too vague for the MSE crowd, if so, please feel free to ask clarifying questions or just remove.

The Chebyshev polynomials are a family of orthogonal polynomials typically defined over the domain $x\in[-1,1]$. The nth Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind takes the form:
$$
T_n(x) = \cos(n \arccos(x)) = \frac{1}{2}((x-(\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n))
$$

For reference, here's a plot of the first 4 Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind:

[[image: The first four <span class=]$T_n(x)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiFLv.png)

The Chebyshev polynomials have an interesting geometric interpretation as well, namely they are the projection of the cosine/sine functions defined on a cylinder onto a bisecting plane.

[image: Image Src: Dedalus, a flexible framework for numerical simulations with spectral elements]

So I had this thought, what if I treated the cylinder as a Riemann surface and stereographically projected the cylinder it onto the whole real line?

Doing a little math, one finds that this encoding induces the following change of variables:

$$
x\mapsto \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$

And carrying out this transformation in the definitions of the Chebyshev polynomials, one finds:

$$
\tilde{T_n}(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x^2}^n}((x-i)^n+(x+i)^n)\\
=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\bigg(\frac{x-i}{x+i}\bigg)^{n/2} + \bigg(\frac{x+i}{x-i}\bigg)^{n/2}\bigg)
$$

Which, when plotted look like:

[image: "stereographically" transformed chebyshev polynomial of the first kind]

Interesting features:

The zeros of the standard Chebyshev polynomials have roots that concentrate near the boundary [-1,1], these polynomials have roots that will actually concentrate near the origin.

One can deal with problems in an unbounded domain, by instead studying a problem in the unit interval.

Main questions:

Are these transformed polynomials related to any already known orthogonal polynomials?

Has this transformation been studied before, if so, what is known about them?

Has this been "useful" in solving any particular problem?

Comment: Your definition of the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind is wrong. Indeed, what you've written isn't even a polynomial.

Comment: You're right. I removed it since it didn't contribute much to the overall discussion and was incorrect

Comment: If $x=\cot t$ then $\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\pm\cos t.$

Comment: So this mean $\tilde T_n(\cot t)=\pm\cos(nt).$

Comment: I would also add that $\tilde T_n$ doesn't seem to be a polynomial. Certainly, more when $n$ is odd.

Comment: When $n$ is even, the only way for $(1+x^2)^{n/2}$ to be a factor of the numerator is if  $i$ and $-i$ are roots of the numerator. This is not the case with $(x-i)^n+(x+i)^n.$

Comment: You're right, is it a Laurent series?

Comment: It might *have* a Laurent series. It is certainly an analytic.